# Is there any way to install Apple Bonjour SDK on windows via command line (for Github Actions)?

Tags: windows, electron, github-actions, bonjour, mdns

I'm developing an Electron Application which uses the Apple Bonjour (https://developer.apple.com/bonjour/), and to compile its native dependencies I need to install the Apple Bonjour SDK for each specific OS.

My CI/CD pipeline is running on Github Actions, which provides me Windows, Ubuntu and MacOS virtual machines. Installing the SDK for Ubuntu and MacOS was pretty easy, however I couldn't find any way to make it work for windows machines via command line.

Does anyone have experience automatising the compilation of the bonjour libraries in windows machines via command line?

I know I could download the SDK and install it manually via interface on windows but I need this via command line because I need to run it on my CI pipeline on Github Actions.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? Got the same scenario, I need the header for the mdns nodejs package, but need to install it via a workflow. Easy for Linux and Mac, but windows is the edge case

Comment: @Timmo unfortunally I did not, the only workaround that I managed to do is: I'm building my electron application in a MacOS machine but targetting Windows, and to properly compile my windows dependencies I am using wine-deps and wine in my macos machine. At least in this way I managed to build my bonjour package for a windows distribution